# UITextAlignmentCenter for two liners with same number of characters, not aligned

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a UILabel with text: 照明タイマーをセットする that is being cut into two lines "照明タイマー" and "をセットする", I set the lines of alignment of the UILabel to UITextAlignmentCenter, but the second line wouldn't align to center. I have also tried UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap and UILineBreakModeWordWrap, but it's still the same. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting it up in interface builder works fine.. have you solved it?

[image: UILabel in Interface Builder]

Comment: yup, I did solve it, forgot how though.. it was almost a year ago :)) old question :)) thanks for the answer anyway! :D

Comment: haha sry i didn't look at the date. just clicked through stackoverflow :PP